# json data grouping based on conditions in node.js

Tags: json, node.js

```
{
    "table": "alltrades",
    "rows":
    [
        {
            "timestamp": 1458042948000,
            "tid": 4525616,
            "price": 0.03137600,
            "amount": 2.18500000,
            "type": 1
        },
        {
            "timestamp": 1458042949000,
            "tid": 4525617,
            "price": 0.03137600,
            "amount": 2.18500000,
            "type": 1
        },
        {
            "timestamp": 1458042952000,
            "tid": 4525618,
            "price": 0.03137500,
            "amount": 0.00477131,
            "type": 2
        },
        {
            "timestamp": 1458042953000,
            "tid": 4525619,
            "price": 0.03137500,
            "amount": 0.00475697,
            "type": 2
        },
        {
            "timestamp": 1458042953000,
            "tid": 4525620,
            "price": 0.03137500,
            "amount": 0.00037928,
            "type": 2
        },
        {
            "timestamp": 1458042954000,
            "tid": 4525621,
            "price": 0.03137500,
            "amount": 0.00024350,
            "type": 2
        },
        {
            "timestamp": 1458042954000,
            "tid": 4525622,
            "price": 0.03137500,
            "amount": 2.00000000,
            "type": 2
        },
        {
            "timestamp": 1458042954000,
            "tid": 4525623,
            "price": 0.03137600,
            "amount": 0.00018831,
            "type": 1
        },
        {
            "timestamp": 1458042955000,
            "tid": 4525624,
            "price": 0.03137600,
            "amount": 0.00003273,
            "type": 1
        },
        {
            "timestamp": 1458042957000,
            "tid": 4525625,
            "price": 0.03137600,
            "amount": 0.00077868,
            "type": 1
        },
        {
            "timestamp": 1458042958000,
            "tid": 4525626,
            "price": 0.03137600,
            "amount": 0.00000411,
            "type": 1
        }]
}
```

I have data like above I need to group them based on following conditions
where type `1=buy` , `2=sell`, `tid` means exchange
if we one buy happens at time x, another buy 1 second later, another buy 1 second after that and another buy 1 second later and then 3 seconds no trades and then another buy
then we have 4 trades
that we need to sum together
and then a break of 3 seconds
after which another buy happens, but we will not add that one then, probably the best is to return `timestamp x`
including `duration: 3 seconds` with total amount and VWAP price and `type=buy`  or `type=sell`.

So condition like that same exchange, same type and 1 sec time interval between them then group data like 
`average = (amount*price + amount1*price1)/(amount + amount1)`

and if exchange different or type different or time interval different than leave it as it is.

Comment: And what is the problem? `for (let trade of trades) { if (trade.type === 1 && /* whatever */) /* find all matches here */ }`

Comment: but how make that same trade same type and one sec. interval then agrigate them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var last = 0;
    var last1 = 0;
    var tmp = _.groupBy(obj["rows"], function(d){ 
        var test2 =  d["timestamp"];
        if(last == 0){
            last = test2;
        }else{
            if((test2 - last1) <= 1000 && (test2 - last1) >= 0){

            }
            else
            {
                last = test2;
            }
        }
        last1 = test2;
      return last;
    });
    // Show the temporary result :o)
    // Now group the result with currency code
    var tmp2 = {};
    _.each(tmp, function(t, unit){
        tmp2[unit] = _.groupBy(t, function(d){
        return d["type"];
        });
    });


    // show the temp result again
    var finalResult = [];
    _.each(tmp2, function(t, unit){
      _.each(t, function(items, currency){
        var total = 0;
        var totalamount = 0;
        var count = 0;
        var VWAP = 0;
        //console.log(items);
        _.each(items, function(item){
          total += item["price"];     // should also * currencyCode?
          totalamount += item["amount"];
          VWAP += item["price"] * item["amount"];
          count++;
        });
        finalResult.push({
            "timestamp" : unit
          , "price" : total
          , "amount" : totalamount
          , "VWAP" : VWAP/count
          , "type" : currency    // Update it yourself :o)
          , "count" : count
        });
      });
    });

    console.log(finalResult);
```

Comment: i used the above function to agrigate the json data